# How does Laravel CSRF protection protect itself from sub-domain cookie overwrite attacks?

Tags: laravel, cookies, subdomain, csrf

Laravel seems to use 2 different patterns for CSRF attacks.

The first one: Laravel store a token in server session named `_token`, and refreshed it for every request. Then put  `{{ csrf_field() }}` in a form, so that when the form is submitted, it will carry the hidden input value contains the csrf token back to server, to see whether it matches the value of `_token` stored in session. This is the synchronizer token pattern.

But the second one is what I am worried about. Laravel uses Double Submit Cookie pattern for AJAX calls. Laravel stores a cookie named `XSRF-TOKEN` on the client side along with the encrypted session_id cookie. The client application will read that `XSRF-Token` cookie to custom the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` request header, and put the cookie value in that header. So Laravel will only check if the `XSRF-Token` cookie value matches `X-XSRF-TOKEN` of the request header or not.

This is the problem. Why Laravel didn't force the `XSRF-Token` cookie value and `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header value to be the same as `_token` in session? If Laravel blindly trust the client side's cookie and request header, what happened if the attacked owns the sub-domain, and overwrites the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie and forge the request?

How is Laravel able to protect itself from sub-domain cookie attack if it use Double Submit Cookie pattern for its `AJAX call`?